# Mind map software with publicly accessible API?

Tags: windows, diagram, mind-mapping

**Background Info:** I frequently listen to podcasts and like to jot down notes. When I can't (because I'm driving or doing something else), I use a voice assistant on my smartwatch to convert my speech to text and enter it into a Google Sheets spreadsheet (this is done via HTTP request in the "Tasker" Android app). However, despite being able to specify which cell to place each note, I still find my spreadsheets awkward to navigate. I recently discovered mind map/concept map software and am wondering if I could replace Google Sheets with one of them.

**Mind Map Desired Features:**

- API enables programmatic editing of mind maps. I would like to be able to search a mind map for a node with a particular string, and then add a child node under it with whatever text I specify.
- Allows for non-hierarchical relationships (e.g. one node can have multiple parent nodes)
- Supports cross-map linking (clicking a node on one mind map opens up an entirely new mind map)
- Supports attaching/linking documents to a node
- Offers multiple relationship types (i.e. there isn't just one type of line to connect two nodes)
- Collapsible nodes
- Windows compatible

I'm completely new to this site and programming in general so I apologize if this topic has been covered or if my post is confusing or improperly phrased. Thanks in advance for your help!